# How to add multiple amount in PayPal recurring payment?

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I want to use recurring biling system in my website.
For that my requirement is

**"A customer purchases a $300 annual plan.  Next year it will automatically take another payment for renewal at $250 which is slightly lower than the original $300."**

Below is the example:

```
<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="chinmay235-facilitator@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Test Prouct" />
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="250.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

From the above example takes one amount which is `a3` as recurring amount $250 each year once but i need the recurring billing system takes $300 for the first time and the recurring billing amount is $250

Please let me know what should be the parameter for one time payment which is $300

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="chinmay235-facilitator@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Test Prouct" />
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="300.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="250.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="AngellEYE_PHPClass">
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Let me know what is `AngellEYE_PHPClass` ?

Comment: It's my PayPal partner code so they know I helped you.  It's not required, but would be appreciated if you include it.  :)